# No curly brackets causing 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'. Can someone tell why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hook-form

I'm using useFieldArray of React Hook Form, and what I'm trying to do is on useEffect load array from database to multiple `tool` fields each. But the code below gives the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` unless I put curly braces around both
`content = ''` and `content` in the function. Like `addTool({content})` and so on. And I don't have any idea why

Not works:

```
const addTool = (content = '') => {
    toolAppend({ name: content })
  }
```

```
projData.tool.map((content, index) => {
        addTool(content)
      })
```

Works:

```
const addTool = ({content = ''}) => {
    toolAppend({ name: content })
  }
```

```
projData.tool.map((content, index) => {
        addTool({content})
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `useFieldArray` functions (append, remove etc.) quickly throws a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error if the data handled by your form is malformed.

```js
const inner = {}

const outer = {
  first: inner,
  nested: {
    // referencing the same object twice will crash,
    //  same as circular structures.
    second: inner   
  },
  someAction: () => {} // functions will also crash
}
```

It's a bit hard to tell what the exact problem in your case is/was, but there maybe was superfluous data on your `tool` entries, which got removed by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) them.

### TL;DR

Make sure the data handled by your form doesn't contain anything "fancy": circular structures, referencing the same object multiple times, functions ...